# How to understand if a contract has been renounced programmatically?

Tags: web3js, blockchain, ethers.js

Is there a way to query the blockchain to find out the current owner of the smart contract programmatically? I mean not the address that deployed the contract, but the one that is currently the owner.

These might not be the same if the previous owner renounced or transferred ownership.

Maybe there is a method in ethers.js, web3.js, or GraphQL to check if the current owner is still the address that deployed the contract?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the contract uses the openzeppelin implementation of ownable, I believe there is an event you can listen for. Contracts can have custom ownership implementations, as well as custom permissioning structures, so it will also depend on the specific contract you care about, and its specific code